# How to open a file in write mode which is in ROOT?

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, file-io, root

I have a file in the root directory which I want to open for editing in my QT application. 
Generally we use sudo  filepath to open the file with all permissions.
But i want to achieve this in my c++ QT application.
Any kind of help is appreciable. 
Thank you.

Comment: Being in the root directory has nothing to do with the file permissions. But if you need special permissions, you need to run your application as a user with the right permissions. Maybe look at [setuid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following.

- Get userid, if it is not 0 (uid of root is 0), the do the following
- Execute argv[0] with gksu/kdesu.
- Perform tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Your program needs to be executed with root privileges, or, more specifically, it needs to be executed as a user who has access permissions for those files.

If it is not, then it is **impossible** to access those files, because the OS will not allow your program to do so. There are no changes in the C++ code that will fix this. You need to execute your program using `sudo`.